# docker-compose push Multiple Services Spring Boot MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am very new to Docker so please bear with me if I don't have a good grasp of the concepts. Basically I am trying to push two services to `dockerhub` - one is my Spring application, and the other is MySQL which is my backend database. I've written the below `Dockerfile` for my Java application:

```
FROM openjdk:15-jdk-alpine

COPY application/target/application.jar /application.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/application.jar"]
```

And this is my `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
version: '3'
services:
  application-db:
    restart: always
    container_name: application-db
    image: 'mysql:5.7.30'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: application_database
      MYSQL_USER: alee
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: anotherpassword
    ports:
      - '3308:3306'
    volumes:
      - './initial.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial.sql'
  application-app:
    restart: on-failure
    image: decade3/sim_backend:first_commit
    build: ./
    expose:
      - '8080'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://application-db:3306/application_database?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: alee
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: anotherpassword
    depends_on:
      - application-db
```

When I `docker-compose up` everything runs locally, and I am able to run my app locally with the adequate http requests and interact with the mysql database.

Now I am trying to do a `docker-compose push` into dockerhub - I don't think it's possible to push these two services into dockerhub and get them to "interact" with one another from what I have read.

How do I go about pushing these two separate images into dockerhub, so that when I pull the image, the application is able to run locally on different machines? Or do they have to be done separately?

Comment: I think the scenario is: 1. You push push/publish your images to the Registry (Docker Hub or any) 2. Push (Share) your docker-compose to a public/private repository 3. You pull your images from the Registry using the docker-compose file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you need to push only 1 service to Dockerhub, that is Java service. 
The mysql image is already public image so that configuration wont change.

To build docker image for spring you can do

```sh
docker build -f Dockerfile .
```

Then run your commands to push the image to dockerhub

and your production docker-compose.yml becomes (notice image for application-app service)

```
version: '3'
services:
  application-db:
    restart: always
    container_name: application-db
    image: 'mysql:5.7.30'
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: application_database
      MYSQL_USER: alee
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: anotherpassword
    ports:
      - '3308:3306'
    volumes:
      - './initial.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/initial.sql'
  application-app:
    restart: on-failure

    image: DOCKERHUB_IMAGE_PATH:latest

    build: ./
    expose:
      - '8080'
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://application-db:3306/application_database?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: alee
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: anotherpassword
    depends_on:
      - application-db
```

Comment: Thanks very much ssnk!

Answer (score 0):

You need to push each image separately to dockerhub and wherever you want to use these images in tandem, you'll use the compose file to orchestrate between them.